# Blurred book in "X-Men: The Animated Series" Season 4, Episode 5, "Proteus - Part II"

Tags: x-men-the-animated-series

I was watching the Proteus episodes of *X-Men: The Animated Series* in Season 4, and I noticed a blurred book in [Episode 5, "Proteus - Part II"](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men:_The_Animated_Series_Season_4_5).

[image: the blurred book]

After a little digging, I found out that the book's title is *The Making of the President, 1968*.

I was just curious as to why this is blurred.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sc71GpPezxA&feature=share The book is visible here at 7:51 - unblurred, though that doesn’t answer the question. I’m not familiar with the book - perhaps is against what Disney stands for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on previous examples I have heard of this happening in television, I doubt it was censored for political reasons but more likely that the studio couldn’t get the rights to use the cover image. The author or publisher might have not wanted the book associated with a cartoon or comic book or simply had a blanket stand of it not being used in television.

I know there was a film based off of the book which means a competing studio might own the rights.
This would also make sense if it is visible on versions aired on tv but not through other distribution methods